# 2D array property

Tags: c#, properties, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to write a property for a 2D array that returns a specific element of an array ? I'm pretty sure I'm not looking for an indexer because they array belongs to a static class.

Comment: Can't get your question, please ellaborate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want a property with parameters - which is basically what an indexer is. However, you can't write static indexers in C#.

Of course you *could* just write a property which returns the array - but I assume you don't want to do that for reasons of encapsulation.

Another alternative would be to write `GetFoo(int x, int y)` and `SetFoo(int x, int y, int value)` methods.

Yet another alternative would be to write a wrapper type around the array and return *that* as a property. The wrapper type could have an indexer - maybe just a readonly one, for example:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private readonly T[,] array;

    public Wrapper(T[,] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        return array[x, y];
    }

    public int Rows { get { return array.GetUpperBound(0); } }
    public int Columns { get { return array.GetUpperBound(1); } }
}
```

Then:

```
public static class Foo
{
    private static readonly int[,] data = ...;

    // Could also cache the Wrapper and return the same one each time.
    public static Wrapper<int> Data
    {
        get { return new Wrapper<int>(data); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought we couldn't return the array through a property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx Ignoring that, you answered my question.

Comment: @Andrew: *couldn't* and *shouldn't* aren't the same thing. You *can* return a reference to an array - but then you have no control over how that array is used.

Comment: I assume the property implementation should read `return array[x, y];`, not `return this[x, y];` (which will give an infinite recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
array[x][y]
```

Where x is the row and y is the column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?:

```
public string this[int x, int y] 
{
   get { return TextArray[x, y]; }
   set { TextArray[x, y] = value; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's in a static class, and therefore has to be a static member. You can't create a static indexer in C#.